# This message parameter has to be of type: Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parameters, collision

I have done this in 3D.
I don't have "is trigger" chosen in any objects.
I wanted to write down "it works" when my object hit an object that is tagged "Obstacle". I need help.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            Debug.Log("it works");
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm new to Unity so please try to explain as I could understand TYSM.)

Comment: Rename your script from `Collision` to something else, like `CollisionTesting`.  Collision is already a type used by the game engine.  Alternatively, you can explicitly resolve the parameter Collision by including its namespace.  `void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collision)`

Answer (score 1):

UnityEngine has a class [Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html) simply rename your class and the file containing it.

Comment: My goodness, I made the exact same mistake naming my class Collision XD

Answer (score 0):

You should add the **Rigidbody** component to the object. It is necessary for collision detection

Comment: I hace already done it but anyways I decided to learn some C# before unity. TY